# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable on execution sum() function in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying a very basic code in python and running the same on Jupyter:

```
while t>0:
    t = t-1
    array = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
    print(array)
    array.sort()
    print(sum(array[-3:]))
```

### But on running the code i am getting the below error as :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-7b432f625fee> in <module>
      1 lts = [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8]
----> 2 print(sum(lts[::]))

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Provide complete code snippet

Comment: Your trace back doesn't match the code. Most likely you have shadowed the built in sum function with an integer.